# NSUserDefaults - UIPickerView

Tags: uipickerview, nsuserdefaults

I want to save position and the choice of a `UIPickerView`. With `NSUserDefaults` it is one picker with 5 rows.

```
NSInteger selectedRow = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:selectedRow forKey:@"picker"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Save 'selectedRow' as an NSNumber instead of NSInteger.  This is because NSUserDefaults can usually only store objects of type NSString, NSNumber, NSData, NSDate, NSArray or NSDictionary.  You can do this by doing:

```
NSNumber *myNum = [NSInteger numberWithInteger:selectedRow];
```

After that all you have to do is save the NSNumber 'myNum' into the NSUserDefaults.
If that doesn't work, make sure to synchronize your NSUserDefaults with the 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] call.
Hope this helped!